# Pick algorithm with runtime in O(n) vs. Θ(n) vs. Ω(\log n )

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

> You are given three algorithms, $A$, $B$, and $C$ with the following time complexities *in the worst case* $O(n)$, $\Theta(n)$, and $\Omega(\log n )$, respectively.
>
> Assume that you have to choose exactly one algorithm, what would you choose as the best algorithm? Explain your answer.

I think I cannot choose $C$ because I cannot guarantee that the complexity is very large, i.e., $2^n$.

I would choose $A$ and not $B$. Why?
Well $A$ could have a very low complexity since its complexity is $O(n)$ so complexity of $A$ is less than $c\cdot n$. But, $B$ is always bounded from above and from below by $c\cdot n$.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yep. It makes sense. (Although you wanted to write that you don't choose $C$ because you cannot guarantee that the complexity is *not* very large..)

Comment: That is the answer expected from you. The best answer, short of more details on these algorithm. In practice, there may be other aspects to be considered for choising an algorithm, An algorithm with bad asymptotic complexity may still be the faster one on small inputs.

Comment: "so complexity of A is less than c⋅n" -- maybe, but not necessarily. In truth, you don't have enough data; even the $\Theta(n)$ algorithm may be faster on most inputs. I'd probably go with $B$; if $A$ so hard to analyse that we only have an upper bound but $B$ is not, chances are it's 1) easier to implement correctly and 2) fast in practice (because "simple").